# transformation of circle & sinusoid functions

Tags: trigonometry

If we are travelling around the circle with center not at the origin, (2,-5), and radius 3, counterclockwise, starting not at (r,0), but (4, √5-5), let P(x,y) be the point where you end up. How do I find equations for x,y?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE . Kindly show us what you have tried and where you are stuck

Comment: What is the equation of the circle? What is the speed of travel? Could you assume starting point $(x_0,y_0)$?